# Vagrant Install-ChocolateyInstallPackage: $File parameter not recognized

Tags: powershell, vagrant, package-managers, chocolatey

I am creating my own `chocolatey` package and I am using `Install-ChocolateyInstallPackge` for software installation. According to its documentation, this function takes a `HashTable` to pass arguments to its parameters. I have the following ones:

```
 #File:  chocolateyInstall.ps1
 $ErrorActionPreference="stop"
 $toolsDir = $(Split-Path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition)
 $installFile = Join-Path $toolsDir "jdk8u211windowsx64.exe" # JDK.exe is in parent
 ....
 $packageArgs = @{
    PackageName    = 'jdk8da'
    FileType       = 'exe'
    SoftwareName   = 'JDK8*'
    File           = $installFile
    SilentArgs     = '/s ADDLOCAL="ToolsFeature" INSTALLDIR=C:\JAVA'
    ValidExitCodes = @(0)
 }

 Install-ChocolateyInstallPackage $packageArgs

 .... #Setting Environment Variables....
```

However, I am getting an error:

```
ERROR: Package parameters incorrect, either File or File64 must be specified
```

As it can be seen that I have clearly specified the `exe` file with fill path.

It works if I specify the File parameter direct to the function:

```
Install-ChocolateyInstallPackage -PackageName "JDK8" -FileType "exe" -File $installFile ....
```

Where am I missing, can anyone point that out please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Due to the fact that you are using “splatting” of the PowerShell parameters, you have to use a slightly different syntax when actually using the `packageArgs` variable.

You should be doing this:

```
Install-ChocolateyInstallPackage @packageArgs
```

Rather than:

```
Install-ChocolateyInstallPackage $packageArgs
```

Have a look here:

https://github.com/chocolatey-community/chocolatey-coreteampackages/blob/master/automatic/calibre/tools/chocolateyInstall.ps1

For a complete example.

Comment: Thanks @ sign fixed it, I need to brush up my powershell skills more, I missed the splatting feature. It is working now.

Comment: @DilshadAbduwali glad to hear that you got it working! 